# Nested Dictionary list of Dictonaries retrieving value in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

the nested mess looks like this:

```
{ Users : [
    {'Username': 'abc', 'Attributes' : [{'a':'x'},{'b':x'}]},
    {'Username' : 'def' ...}
]}
```

I tried :

```
for k,v in users.items() :
    for i in v :
        for k,v in i :
            if k == 'Username' :
                print(v)
```

and the error was

```
"errorMessage": "too many values to unpack (expected 2)"
```

tried :

```
for v in users['Users'] :
    for i in v :
       for k in v[i] :
           print(k)
```

error message:

```
"errorMessage": "not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)"
```

I need to retrieve the value of 'Username' and put them in a simple list.  Can someone point out what I am not getting right here?

Comment: `for user in users["Users"]: print(user["Username"])`?

Comment: `for k,v in i.items()` :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were so close:

```
usernames = []
for k,v in users.items():
    for i in v:
        for k,v in i.items():
            #       ^^^^^^^^ you were just missing one more `.items()` call
            if k == 'Username':
                usernames.append(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just did one mistake, you have to make a for loop for the dict. items, check the code below,

```
data = { 'Users' : [{'Username': 'abc', 'Attributes' : [{'a':'x'},{'b':'x'}] }]}

for k,v in data.items() :
    for i in v :
        for k,v in i.items() :
            if k == 'Username' :
                print(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are levels of recursion which can be removed here. Assuming there is only 1 key of Users.

```
data = {
    "Users": [
        {"Username": "abc", "Attributes": [{"a": "x"}, {"b": "x"}]},
        {"Username": "def", "Attributes": [{"a": "x"}, {"b": "x"}]},
    ]
}

users = data["Users"]

usernames = [user["Username"] for user in users]

print(usernames)
```